# Parsing a text and get the occurences of a given word using its root

Tags: java, parsing, text-files

I am working on a system that gives the exact sense of a given word (obviously polysemous word) based on its context. This area of study called Word Sense Disambiguation. for that purpose, I need the root (steam) of the given word and a text that contain it. I will parse the text and find all the occurrences of the given word using its root.

For example if the given word is "love". The system will parse the text and returns all the occurrences of "love" like "lovely, loved, beloved..."

Below is what I tried but unfortunately I didn't get what I want!

```
public class Partenn1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int c=0;
        String w = "tissue";

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/Sc46.txt")))
        {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] WrdsLine = line.split(" ");

                boolean findwrd = false;
                for( String WrdLine : WrdsLine )
                {
                    for (int a=0; a<WrdsLine.length; a++)
                    {
                        if ( WrdsLine[a].indexOf(w)!=0)
                        {
                            c++; //It's just a counter for verification of the numbre of the occ.
                            findwrd = true; 
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            System.out.println(c);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: kindly post clearly as to what you want and what you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root of a word is also known as the prefix of the word. This can be achieved by calling the method startsWith on the string with the corresponding prefix.

The following code correctly prints out '2', since both 'tissue2' and 'tissue3' are starting with 'tissue'.

```
int count = 0;
final String prefix = "tissue";

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader("tissue2 tiss tiss3 tissue3"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // Get all the words on this line
        final String[] wordsInLine = line.split(" ");

        for (final String s : wordsInLine) {
            // Check that the word starts with the prefix.
            if (s.startsWith(prefix)) {
                count++;
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println(count);
} catch (final IOException ignored) {
}
```

Comment: noo I am working with arabic word! it doesn't work like that!

Comment: You should give more example data and point out what error you get in order to further enhance the answer. Currently it is too unclear what you are trying to obtain and which exact scenario can break the code posted.

Comment: I think its pretty much clear! I just want to get evry occurense of a pattern in a file
the methode `indexOf` dont work here be cose its ork with 2 string and i hae one Strin ane the ather is Strin[] (WrdsLine) I tried to convert it but i couldn't get it

Answer (score 1):

No need for one more `for` loop. `w` is desired string here :

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] WrdsLine = line.split(" "); // split

                for( String WrdLine : WrdsLine ) {

                    if ( WrdLine.contains(w)) { // if match - print
                        System.out.println(WrdLine);
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: this code will give us only thi Exact words that are equals to w... and dont give all the occurences! and the other for is to getting each word form the line (from String [] to String)